# Finding the cardinality of exactly one or two elements of two or three finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, combinatorics

IF $A$,$B$,$C$ are finite sets then,

Number of elements in exactly one of sets $A$,$B$,$C$:$$n(A)+n(B)+n(C)-2 \times n(A \cap B)-2 \times n(A \cap C)-2 \times n(C \cap B) + 3 \times n(A \cap B \cap C)$$

Number of elements in exactly two of the sets $A$,$B$,$C$: $$n(A \cap B)+(A \cap C)+n(C \cap B) - 3 \times n(A \cap B \cap C)$$

Could somebody explain how can we prove them? I think it's something with inclusion and exclusion but am not getting how to get those results.Also I think we can have a generalized results for these kinds ?!

Comment: It is exactly PIE (inclusion-exclusion). 
This is trivial though with a Venn diagram.

Comment: This could be helpful: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/InclusionExclusion.shtml and http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~baik/Teaching/inclusion-exclusion.pdf

Comment: Please change the title to something more descriptive.

Comment: @Moron:Please check.

Comment: Deb: Seems ok...

Comment: @InterestedGuest That first link is what you need. See point 
(2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about inclusion and exclusion.

For the number of elements in exactly one of the sets, you first count all $n(A) + n(B) + n(C)$ elements.  You disregard the $n(A \cap B)$ elements twice, as you need to disregard them from your count for both $A$ and $B$.  The logic is similar for $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$.  Finally, you've disregarded the $n(A \cap B \cap C)$ elements in all three sets twice, so you have to correct the count by adding this quantity back in.

I bet you can figure out the second one once you've carefully understood the first.

Comment: Thanks, I understood,it was really trivial on analyzing with a venn diagram.